# Keep element with a percentage as a position fixed

Tags: html, css, dom, position

I have a container of variable height, and would like to put an element at the middle of it. So I've set these styles:

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
}

#child {
    position: absolute;

    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Which work in most cases. However, the container's height is not only variable, but it also changes constantly.
Because of this, that code won't work. An example:

```css
@keyframes changeSize {
  0% {
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  50% {
    height: 150px;
  }
  
  100% {
    height: 100px;
  }
}


#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  
  animation-name: changeSize;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p id="child">I should not be moving...</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, it's moving. So, my question is, **is there a way to place it in the middle of the element (vertically) but without having it move if the container changes size - just with CSS?**

Comment: The only way I see to resolve this is a JavaScript solution. Percentage units on #child are relative to the containing element. Since the height of the containing element is changing, you are noticing the unit change. You need to use fixed units (like pixels). The only way to get an initial 50% reading in pixels is with JavaScript. Writing an answer now...

Comment: if the height is fixed intially the why not simply use it to define the top value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that percentage measure units are relative to the containing element. Since the #parent is changing in height through the animation, the value of a percentage unit changes. The unit change affects the percentage height property applied to the #child. The work-around might be some very complicated CSS (might not work in every situation) so the best solution is to use JavaScript to capture the initial 50% height in pixels so the unit no longer changes. It is important to also use a `resize` event listener to apply a new 50% height should the browser window be resized.

```js
window.addEventListener('load',resizeDiv());
window.addEventListener('resize',resizeDiv());

function resizeDiv(){
  var initialHeight = document.getElementById('parent').offsetHeight/2;
  document.getElementById('child').style.top = initialHeight+'px';
}
```

```css
@keyframes changeSize {
  0% {
    height: 100px;
  }

  50% {
    height: 150px;
  }

  100% {
    height: 100px;
  }
}


#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;

  animation-name: changeSize;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p id="child">Hey!! I'm not moving anymore!</p>
</div>
```